# Passing an object of the current class to another class

Tags: java, object

Okay, I'm unsure whether this is a stupid question or not.

I'm trying to ensure that I use as little static methods in my code as possible as at the moment its a complete mess, I want to create as best an OO approach as possible.

Is it considered **bad practice** to create an object of the current class you're in and then to pass the value?

is it even possible?

for example..

```
    public class Details{
        int age;
        String name;
        String countryOfBirth;

        public Details(int age, String name, String countryOfBith){
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name
            this.countryOfBirth = countryOfBirth;
        }

        // how would I use these values to then pass them to another class as an object?

        Candidate can = new Candidate(Details 

}
```

The reason I need to know this is because I wish to use methods within this specific class corresponding to the values in the class. I'm using semaphores if you need to know that

For example, I want to pass the object but I only want one specific value..

Comment: If I understand your question correctly; then yes. You can. And it is most certainly in the OO approach to do it that way.

Comment: please provide a little more context, I do not understand the last line in your example

Comment: yeah sure @luk2302  I just updated

Comment: Well if you're creating an object of your current class, with the same values, you might as well just use the `this` keyword; unless of course, you're trying to make this object immutable.

Comment: You can pass the object. If you only want the values, you could just pass the values, like `this.age`.

Comment: oh really? thats brilliant, i'll give it a shot.. is this considered bad code or just a general approach? @mmking

Comment: It really depends on what you want. If you need the Details object, you can pass it to the Candidate class in the constructor. If you don't need it and just need the values, just pass in the values. There's no sense to pass in the object if you just need the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to do so, and most commonly in a console application an instance of the class containing the `main`method is often created in the `main` method itself and used to do one thing or the other. The following demonstrates the point:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.say();
    }

    public void say() {
        System.out.println ("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

With the the example you provided in context, it's fine to write

```
Candidate can = new Candidate(this);
```